# PostgreSQL driver for Go programming language

Tags: database, postgresql, driver, go

http://go-lang.cat-v.org/pure-go-libs lists two PosgreSQL drivers, but they haven't been updated since months and looking like one man shows. So I wonder if they are reliable / ready for production or if there are other recommended drivers.

Would you use Go with PostgreSQL for production and with what driver?

Comment: What's wrong with a driver that hasn't been updated "*in months*". There is one PostgreSQL release per year. Why should the driver be updated more often if everything is working? Btw: https://github.com/bmizerany/pq has been updated 15 days ago.

Comment: There is nothing wrong per se, but I've made the experience that it is a bad sign.

Comment: I personally find something that is updated frequently (every month) more irritating than something that has a (stable) release once a year.

Comment: Depends on the maturity - and I wouldn't consider most go libraries that mature (because they are young).

Answer (score 11):

In the year and a half since this question was asked, [**pq**](https://github.com/lib/pq) has matured significantly and is actively maintained (multiple commits by multiple people in the last week, consistent weekly updates for the last several months).

Docs are here: http://godoc.org/github.com/lib/pq

Answer (score 4):

A list of SQL DB drivers can be found [here](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/SQLDrivers)

Answer (score 2):

On this basis I probably wouldn't **go** for it in production...

The newest one seems to be https://github.com/jbarham/gopgsqldriver

But one of the advantages of open source is that you have all the source so you can maintain it yourself, contribute patches or even take over the maintainer's role.

Comment: Thanks. The [driver](https://github.com/bmizerany/pq) mentioned by a_horse_with_no_name seems to be more recent. But I'll look at both.

Comment: Report back here, especially your experience using in production.

Comment: I felt to unproductive with Go and switched to Scala. If I start again  programming in Go and use PostgreSQL, I'll report here.